# Why is the Riemann $\int_0^1 1 / \sqrt{x}$ not defined?

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

On $(0, 1]$, let $f(x) = 1/\sqrt{x}$ with $f(0) = 0$. Let $I = [0,1]$.

Is it then true that the Lebesgue $\int_I f < \infty$, while the Riemann $\int_0^1 f$ isn't even defined? If so, why is the Riemann $\int_0^1 f$ not defined?

Comment: Because that function is bounded and not continue at $x= 0$

Comment: @GuyFsone No, the function is unbounded, and continuity at $0$ has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Yes your right just a typo. I want to write NOT bounded as well:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By definition the proper Riemann integral acts on bounded functions. It is also only defined on compact intervals, though that is not really the problem here (one can define $f(x)=x^{-1/2}$ on $(0,1]$ and $0$ at $x=0$ for example).

The restriction to bounded functions is motivated by the simple fact that if you have an unbounded function then you can choose your partition to "zoom in" on the singularity which will hinder convergence. Assuming you did the change I mentioned above, you could see the problem by considering the partition $\{ 0,1/n,\dots,1 \}$ and then choosing the evaluation point in $[0,1/n]$ to be, say, $n^{-4}$. Then there is no hope of convergence because the Riemann sums for this sequence of partitions and evaluation points exceed $n$.

This provides an interesting example of a failure of *interchange of limits*: if we define

$$g : \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R},g(m,n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left ( \frac{1}{m} + \left ( 1-\frac{1}{m} \right ) \frac{k}{n} \right )^{-1/2} (1/n)$$

then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{m \to \infty} g(m,n)$ and $\lim_{m \to \infty} \lim_{n \to \infty} g(m,n)$ are not the same. The former limit represents taking Riemann sums of $f$ on all of $[0,1]$ with the evaluation points pushed closer and closer to the left endpoint. It blows up. The latter limit represents taking the Riemann integral of $f$ on $[1/m,1]$ and then sending $m \to \infty$. It converges.

Comment: Fully explain+1)

Comment: What's the issue if you "zoom in" on the singularity which hinders convergence? Is that the Riemann rectangles are of infinite size around the singularity? (Super informally?)

Comment: @user1770201 That's the gist of it, though they are never *really* infinite in size unless the function actually takes on the value $\infty$ at some point. But you can pack an arbitrarily large amount of area into an arbitrarily narrow rectangle if you consider an unbounded function, while staying within the framework of Riemann integration.

Comment: @Ian: But in this case, you couldn't actually pack an infinite amount of area; however with functions like $1/x$ you could. Correct? (Here define $1/x(0) = 0$ to make the function defined at $0$).

Comment: @user1770201 No, it would still not be an infinite amount of area in a single rectangle because you don't have any one point where the function takes on the value $\infty$. Understanding the difference between integrable singularities and non-integrable singularities requires improper Riemann integration or Lebesgue integration (or a similar generalization like Lebesgue integration).